# Trigger creation syntax error

Tags: mysql, trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger where I set a colunm to 0 if another column is set to 0 and 1 if it's set higher than 0. This is what I wrote

```
CREATE TRIGGER livre_disponible BEFORE INSERT ON livres
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.nb_exemplaires=0 THEN
            SET NEW.disponible=0;
    ELSEIF NEW.nb_exemplaires>=1 THEN
            SET NEW.disponible=1;
    END IF
END
```

The error is said to be on line 5 which is the first "SET".

I this the correct syntax to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything wrong with your statement, you need perhaps `DELIMITER`s

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `livre_disponible` BEFORE INSERT ON `livres` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
        IF NEW.nb_exemplaires=0 THEN
            SET NEW.disponible=0;
        ELSEIF NEW.nb_exemplaires>=1 THEN
            SET NEW.disponible=1;
        END IF;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Updated : you missed also a ';' ==> `END IF;` `END;`